# How to join two table in sql server only with one row (see details)

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables - ProductOrders (ID, SUM, CreateDate, ProductDescID)  and ProductDesc (ProductDescID, Name). In table ProductDesc i have multiple Names for one product in ProductOrders. I need to join these 2 tables and get only first name of product. For example ProductOrders

```html
ID  ProductDescID  SUM DateCreated 
-----------------------------------
1        1         45   2014-12-30
2        2         34   2013-01-05
3        2         23   2015-02-20
4        3         47   2013-06-04
5        4         12   2012-04-02
```

And ProductDesc

```html
ProductDescID  Name  
------------------------
1               Beverages
1               Beveragessss
2               Vegetables
2               Vegetable
3               Drinks
4               Fruits
```

As the result when i join these two tables i need only first names of ProductDesc (Beverages, Vegetables, Drinks, Fruits)